# Can erc721 belong to another erc721 token?

Tags: erc-721

I learnt somewhere today that an erc721 token doesn't have to belong to an account, it could belong to another erc721!

How can this be implemented? where can I read more of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ERC-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) standard only describes the smart contract interface for a non-fungible token on the Ethereum blockchain. It provides basic functionality to track and transfer NFTs. A token, in this case, can only belong to a physical address - to an account - which can be a user's wallet or another smart contract.

Probably the best you can do is to extend your smart contract and make it chainable. This, however, has nothing to do with the ERC-721 spec.

**UPDATE (20.04.2018):**

I think your use case is targeting [Composable NFT (ERC-998)](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/998) or [Delegated Non-Fungible Tokens (ERC-994)](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/994).

Comment: Thanks got it!! I think i will basically create a new ERC721 that combines both 721 token attribute or something and interpret that as one belongs to the other

Answer (score 0):

The [ERC-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) draft standard requires that each token have one (and only one) owner. The owner of each token is identified by their address, and since an individual ERC-721 token does not have its own address, no this isn't possible.

However, there is no requirement that the owner be a *wallet* address, a token can belong to another contract. So the owner of a token can be another ERC-721 *contract* (or even the same contract), but not another token.